# Hopefully Simple JS Question - Object returing undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object

I'm trying to see if I can get some help understanding what I am doing wrong... Im trying to map through the fetched data and I push it to an array called images then after the map is complete then setFullAdLinks to images array.  The problem is that it keeps saying that fullAdLinks[0].source is undefined when I call setCurrentImage which is after the getAdLinks() function. I have tried using async methods but I haven't been successful. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post code as text and not screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `Promise.all`, which resolves all the fetch calls and set the state.

```js
const getAdLinks = () => {
    const promises = ads.map((ad) => {
        return fetch(ad.image)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => {
                let textLink = res[0].caption.rendered.match(regex);
                let x = {
                    adLink: textLink[0],
                    source: res[0].source_url,
                };
                return x;
            });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(images => {
        setFullAdLinks(images);
    })
};
```

`Promise.all` accepts **array of Promises**, so note the `return` statements everywhere.

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Thank you! I tried Promise.all but I forgot to return x in the .then().